# how to find probability of the events

Tags: probability

A student must choose exactly two out of three electives: Compilers, Algorithms, and Databases. He chooses Compilers with probability 5/8, Algorithms with probability 5/8, and Compilers and Algorithms together with probability 1/4. What is the probability that he chooses Databases? What is the probability that he chooses either Compilers or Algorithms?

Hi guys.....my initial approach for the problem suggests that that the probability for selecting databases is 0 ..... but not sure whether its that trivial.....could anybody confirm the answer ??

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly three exhaustive and mutually exclusive events that can occur:

- The student chooses Compilers and Algorithms only: $C \cap A$
- The student chooses Compilers and Databases only: $C \cap D$
- The student chooses Algorithms and Databases only: $A \cap D$

We're given that $P(C \cap A) = 1/4$. But then since $5/8 = P(C) = P(C \cap A) + P(C \cap D)$, it follows that $P(C \cap D) = 5/8 - 1/4 = 3/8$. Likewise, $P(A \cap D) = 3/8$.

Answer (score 0):

You already said that chance of Compilers and Algorithms is 1/4.  In the remaining cases Databases must be chosen.
1-1/4=3/4